# Switching adapters in GridView?

Tags: android, gridview, listadapter

I have GridView and I want to be able to switch between adapters.

Context:

I have data from two separate sources and I want to be able to easily switch between those.

Is it possible to just switch adapters or there is other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to call `setAdapter` on lists or grids (or any [`AdapterView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html)) multiple times. One caveat: On ListViews, you can't call `addHeaderView` or `addFooterView` once you've made a `setAdapter` call. Alternatively, if it's giving you a hard time just put two GridViews in a [`ViewSwitcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html) (or FrameLayout) with each set to one of the adapters you want and show/hide one or the other when you need to, rather than swapping out sources on one GridView.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it turned out that switching adapters works a lot better and with less overhead than `ViewSwitcher`.